# FileInputStream issue - App has stopped working

Tags: android-studio, java-io, fileinputstream

I am having trouble with `FileInputStream` in `Android Studio`. My application `has stopped working` when I use it to read file `.txt` in the `internal memory` (I have writen data to this file successfully). I have try many solutions but they didn't work. Can anyone give the solution for this problem? Here is my code. Thanks very much. (I have added users-permission `"WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` and `"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`).

```
String fileName = "infoProfile.txt";
private int readData() {
    try {
        String path = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;

        FileInputStream in = openFileInput(path);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
        String data = "";
        while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.add(data);
        }
        in.close();

        if (str.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        etName.setText(str.get(0));
        etEmail.setText(str.get(1));
        etPhone.setText(str.get(2));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: stacktrace needed

Comment: I have never heard about it. Can you explain more clearly or give me some link that is involved with `FileInputStream`?

Comment: you need to provide the error log